# Trouble integrating Barcode Scanner and Database in Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite, expo

Trying to integrate the barcode reader in Expo and a SQLite database. Trying to use a UPC to add to the database. Barcode Scanner complains about incorrect format or doesn't read barcode.

Code here: https://pastebin.com/ZcNJtm2G
And focus area is below.

I've tried googling the problem, looking at tutorials, and just banging my head against it and nothing seems to be working.

```
_handleBarcodeScanned = ({type, data}) => {
    var liquorType;

    if (type==512) {
      db.transaction ((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('select upc from Ingredient', [], (tx, result) => {
          if (result & result.rows && result.rows._array) {
            if (result === data) {
              var ing = rows.item(data).ingredient;
              tx.executeSql('insert into useringredient(user, ingredient, upc) values (user, ?, ?);', [ing, data], () => {
                Alert.alert('insert');
              }); 
            }
          }
          Alert.alert('Drink not found');
        });     
      });
   } else {Alert.alert("Barcode format is not supported");}
  }
```

Comment: does not scan at all ... or it doesn't scan specific files you're using for testing ?

Comment: Doesn't scan at all anymore. We had it scanning before we tried to integrate the database, now it just crashes on scan.

Comment: create an empty project ... then try to run the code in the sample available in the docs for the scanner ... just to figure out if this issue has something to do with your project's setup somehow